# Allow only specific keys on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I have a question. Examples that i find is on a "KeyPress" and they are not longer working on WPF

Can you tell me, how to allow only specified keys from keybord to be write on WPF textbox? I know about keyUp and Down functions, but how to define letters that i want to by type into it?

I think it will be easier, if i will post my code and i tell u what i want to do. What to change here?

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //something here to only allow "A" key to be pressed and displeyed into textbox
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {                
            stoper.Start();
        }
    }

private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            //here i stop the stopwatch to count time of pressing the key
            stoper.Stop();
            string aS = stoper.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            int aI = Convert.ToInt32(aS);
            stoper.Reset();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take some caution in limiting *only* on key presses, as the user can still copy-paste into the textbox, and can also drag-drop literally anything, and watch out for data binding dropping unwanted content.

Comment: That app is for educational purpose, not for developing or for well - payed job :D

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what's wrong with my answer? :( `e.Handled = true;` stops propagating event up the tree. Or you can use `Preview*` events so that the text won't even reach your text box.

Comment: @michasacuer If it's a learning exercise, it could even be a major reason to make it good. That's a good start, I'm just pointing out some other common things that one should consider.

Comment: Johny, where to set e.hendler then? When i type it in "if" on keydown i still can typing everything into textbox

Comment: Everything is in my answer - see example there.

Comment: I know, but when i set e.Handled to true i cant type "A" letter. I need to set ifs to every chars diffrent than my measure keys?

Comment: Create list with forbidden keys and test them: `var keys = new[] { Key.A, Key.D, Key.E }; if (keys.Any(key => key == e.Key)) e.Handled = true;`

Comment: Ok, it was stupid question. I just added "else" statemant and e.Handler on it, thank you very much!

Comment: Good! *Now* you can post an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown) and use `e.Key` to filter out what you need.

Or, in **any** place of your code you can use [Keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard) class:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.E)) { /* your code */ }
```

**UPDATE**:

To forbid a key, you need to set event as handled:

```
if (e.Key == Key.E)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show($"{e.Key.ToString()} is forbidden");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if i have textbox_KeyDown function?

What i want to do, im counting press key time on keyboard. User tiping words that i display on screen and i want to allow only that letters, that are in that words. 

Now, i have something (in key dwon func)
if(e.Key == Key.A) -> Stopwatch.Start

And then in KeyUp func i stop the stopwatch. So how to block other letters that i dont want to ?

Comment: i just post another comment below to show my code and what im intrested in :D

Comment: @michasacuer You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50427556/edit) your post to include explanations rather creating an "answer". Delete the answer and update your origianl post. :)

Answer (score 0):

That thing works pretty fine to me (thanks for @JohnyL):

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //something here to only allow "A" key to be pressed and displeyed into textbox
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {                
        stoper.Start();
    }
    else
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        //here i stop the stopwatch to count time of pressing the key
        stoper.Stop();
        string aS = stoper.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
        int aI = Convert.ToInt32(aS);
        stoper.Reset();
    }
}
```